# Removing specific parts of speech and punctuation from my strings (which are paragraphs) in column A and enter the result in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

See the title. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MakeWordList()
    Dim mObjWord As Word.Application
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WordListSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim wordCnt As Long
    Dim AllWords As Range
    Dim oString As String

    Set mObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set WordListSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
    WordListSheet.Range("A1") = "All Words"
    WordListSheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
    InputSheet.Activate
    wordCnt = 2
    PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", _
        "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", _
        "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*")
    r = 1
    oString = ""
    'Loop until blank cell is encountered and add the word to oString

    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        txt = Cells(r, 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
            txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
        Next i
        'Remove excess spaces
        txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
        'Extract the words
        x = Split(txt)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        Set mObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        ' it does not run from here
            Select Case x(i)
                Case wdAdverb, wdVerb, wdConjunction, wdIdiom, wdInterjection, wdPronoun, wdPreposition
                Case Else
                oString = oString & " " & x(i)
            End Select
        Next i
        InputSheet.Range("r, 2").Value = oString
        r = r + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: RegEx would be a better option.

Comment: I have a Text paragraphs in each cell of column A. I am trying to remove certain parts of speech lick prepositions, verbs, adverbs etc along with punctuation and enter the results in the corresponding cell in column B. I have Reference Library of Microsoft Word selected as well. My program does not run beyond "Select ....." command. I need someone to advise me. I am a rookie.

Comment: please ask an actual question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wish to load an instance of MS Word (actually, your code loads many in a loop, possibly hundreds) to access the enumerations like *wdVerb* which you hope will identify verbs in the text. Enumerations are numbers, long integers to be precise. For example, *wdVerb* represents the value 3 (Type *? wdVerb* in the Immediate window of Word VBE).
I have no idea what Word does with these numbers, but your x(i) holds a string.

```
Select Case x(i)
    Case wdAdverb, wdVerb
    Case Else
```

must therefore always default to *Else* unless it's a 2 or 3 or one of the other numbers you list there.
The first question which comes to my mind is why you don't use Word. Use a Word table in a Word document.
Secondly, your idea can't be made to work. Identifying the verb in "Did I go?" or "I am the go-between" is a big job. Don't expect it to be performed by Word at the drop of a number.
Thirdly, it seems that you wish to extract most words. Why not extract all words first and then make a list of word you want excluded and filter them out.
Finally, your Array(".", ",", ";") seems complicated. The following structure is less voluminous?

```
PuncChars = ".,;" 
and
For i = 1 to Len(PuncChars)
    Txt = Replace(Txt, Mid(PuncChars, i, 1), "")
Next i
```

You would be able to use a very similar system to filter out the words you don't want extracted.

Comment: After making some changes in this code, I was able to run this partially and then it stopped with a runtime error  5824 message saying " Insufficient memory or disk space. Can you take a look at this code and advise what can be done to avoid crashing the memory.:

Comment: This is a totally different kettle of fish now and one of which I don't want any part, not because your question is a follow-up, which I don't do, but because I have no knowledge of it. Ask a new question to reach people who know something about your subject. Meanwhile, I would suspect your object variable MySynInfo to possibly cause the problem. Try Set MySynInfo = Nothing at the end of each loop. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the new code now:

Option Explicit
Sub MakeWordList()
    Dim mObjWord As Word.Application
    Dim mySynInfo As Word.SynonymInfo
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, j As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim oString As String
    Dim myList As Variant
    Dim myPos As Variant
    Dim skipWord As Boolean

    Set mObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet
    InputSheet.Activate
    PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", _
        "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", _
        "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*")
    r = 1
    oString = ""
    'Loop until blank cell is encountered and add the word to oString

    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        txt = Cells(r, 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
            txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
        Next i
        'Remove excess spaces
        txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
        'Extract the words
        x = Split(txt)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        ' getting insufficient memory error at the following command after have
        ' completed a few iteratons of the For loop successfully
            Set mySynInfo = SynonymInfo(Word:=x(i), LanguageID:=wdEnglishUS)
            If mySynInfo.MeaningCount <> 0 Then
                myList = mySynInfo.MeaningList
                myPos = mySynInfo.PartOfSpeechList
                For j = 1 To UBound(myPos)
                    Select Case myPos(j)
                        Case wdAdverb, wdVerb, wdConjunction, wdIdiom, wdInterjection, wdPronoun, wdPreposition
                            skipWord = True
                        Case Else
                            skipWord = False
                    End Select
                Next j
                If Not skipWord Then
                    oString = oString & " " & x(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        InputSheet.Cells(r, 2).Value = oString
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```